# How to make horizontal scrolling in UIWebView in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiwebview

I am loading a pptx file in `UIWebView`,it is  getting loaded and it is scrolled vertically,but  it should be scrolled horizontally.Here is my code.

```
readWebView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
     NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyPPT" ofType:@"pptx"];
      readWebView.scrollView.delegate=self;
        NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        readWebView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
        readWebView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=false;
        readWebView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=true;
        readWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled=YES;
        readWebView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        readWebView.scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
     [readWebView loadRequest:request];
    [self.view addSubview:readWebView];
```

Answer (score 1):

set like

```
readWebView.scrollView.delegate = self;
[readWebView.scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];


-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollVie
{
if (scrollVie.contentOffset.y > 0  ||  scrollVie.contentOffset.y < 0 )
    scrollVie.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollVie.contentOffset.x, 0);
}
```

Comment: this code makes disable the scrollview..there is no scrolling after addition of this code.

Comment: what teh output  u need

Answer (score 0):

Enable Horizontal scrolling and disable Vertical scrolling:

```
myWebView.scrollView.delegate = self;
[myWebView.scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0  ||  scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 )
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0);
}
```

the 2nd line there will hide the vertical scroll indicator. Checking if "scrollView.contentOffset.y < zero" will disable the bouncing when you attempt to scroll downwards. You can also do: scrollView.bounces=NO to do the same thing!! By just looking at Rama Rao's answer i can tell that his code will reset the scrollView to (0.0) the moment you try to scroll vertically, thereby moving you away from your horizontal position, which is not good.

Enable vertical scrolling and disable Horizontal scrolling:

```
myWebView.scrollView.delegate = self;
[myWebview.scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x > 0)
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
}
```